# XSLT calls are broken due to security issues

Tags: javascript, xml, xslt

i'm reformulating this question.

I'm trying to load an XML document that uses some XSLT stylesheets (4 to be precise, conected with xsl:include) from an URL. When I open a new tab with the XML encoded as **data:application/xml,** got the next error:

***Error loading stylesheet: An unknown error has occurred (805303f4)***

and points to the URL of the xsl file.

I have read several posts and find that is about security issues, as a mention, I've tried to accomplish this a couple years ago (Firefox ~v.44 sorta) and it worked nice and clean. To verify, i've installed past versions of FF to tests and the XSL parsing worked in: FF44 - 47 - 56. when I reach Quantum (v.58) spits this error.

To make it 'fancy' my new idea was to put the parsed XML in an iframe, but had no result more than the same error **805303f4**.

At this rate i'm finding doing this a little bit impossible right now, so, if this are security measures, besides of the main question of how to render again the XML in a new tab with data:application that **doesn't implies to downgrade the installed version** of FF in all the clients PCs, how is pretended to be invoked an XSLT file that uses others with xsl:include from an XML?

thanks in advance, and thanks to Martin Honnen for his help in the past question.

*PD: excuse my english*

Comment: Maybe you should report this as a bug to Mozilla.

Comment: i was thinking to do that actually @zx485. what bugs me a lit bit is 1) not only mozilla blocks the xsl loading, chrome does it as well, with an error saying **~"use same domain, protocol, port"** even if the xslt is in the same _"everything"_. 2) why change something and there's no much documentation about alternatives, as far i seek (besides that i'm in a rush) i'll have to wait if maybe somebody has face it this before. Thanks man

Comment: IMHO, this kind of thing is why server side XML / XSL processing is more reliable...

Comment: :o @WilliamWalseth you're absolute precise, I haven't consider it until now that you mention it. Thanks for your comment